# Broken .vcxproj.filter files doesn't break build. What is the best way to maintain .vcxproj.filter files in C++/CLI projects

Tags: xml, c++-cli, projects-and-solutions

In C++/CLi projects, we use filter files to organized the file structure which is very useful. But when this vcxproj.filter file is broken (extra tag/broken XML due to merge conflicts not resolve correctly.), it doesn't break the build. The build is still successful. There is no way for end user to know that they broke the filter file, unless they manually go and see the folder structure in the project.

What is the best way to resolve this issue? One way we know is to unit test the file and check for correct XML ? But this is an overhead, since we don't want to load the XML in memory. It also increase build time on teamcity, since we have more than 10 projects. I was wondering if anyone knew a better approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML schema definition is available, you could run a XML validation as pre-build event.

Command line XML validators should be widely available, e.g. Xerces-C.